# Css browser windows safari and mac safari issue

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Hi everyone i have a css code see below:

```
    .left {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

this will worked in Windows OS with Safari browser and Chrome browser, however it is totally messed up with Mac OS Safari browser. After i debug in Mac it works like this

```
    .left{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: -120px;
    }
```

Somebody help me out with this one.

Comment: how does it look on your Mac? maybe it's not the OS, but the screen size of your pc..

Comment: I test it with the same screen size 1440px but different OS.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but there is no Safari for Windows. Unless you mean the one that was discontinued years ago, which you really shouldn't use to compare against anything. Anyway, one way this difference could be caused would be a media query, like M.Y hints. Or some JavaScript that runs only under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the css for mac .left {margin-left:0;}
Try the below link based on browser.
https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/css-hacks-for-safari-6-1-7-and-8-not-chrome/